# function does not display results when called

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i have a short code here for plugin development. i have been trying different ways in order for the result to be **display in the **textarea****. the problem is it doesn't show up in the textarea. no error just blank. what am i doing wrong? here is my code? hoping for a fast response.

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu','hello_world_plugin');
function hello_world_plugin (){
    add_options_page('Hello Page','Hello Submenu','manage_options',__FILE__,'Hello_Admin');
}

//Insert Data
global $wpdb;
$first = $_POST['firstname'];
$last = $_POST['lastname'];
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $wpdb->insert("wp_options", array(
            "option_name" => $first,
            "option_value" => $last
            )
        );
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Data Submitted!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }

?>                  

<?php   


function Hello_Admin() {

    echo '<div class = "wrap">';
    echo '<h4> Hello World Plugin </h4>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<form action = "" method = "POST">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>';
    echo '<input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value ="Submit to (wp_options)" class = "button-primary"><br><br>';
    echo '<input type = "submit" name = "Display" value ="Display Data from (wp_options)" class = "button-primary"/><br><br>';
    display();
    echo '</form><br>';
}



function display(){
?>
 <textarea cols="50" rows="15">

    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['Display'])) {
    $result = $wpdb->get_results (
                "
                SELECT * FROM wp_options
                WHERE option_id = '262'
                "
        );
        print_r($result);
    }

    ?>
 </textarea>

<?php  

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about wordpress plugins but, this code looks weird to me. In function display(), you should store the  string into a variable and add the result to the variable.

```
    $textarea = '<textarea.....>'; 
    // your wordpress stuff to get the result here
    $textarea .= $result; 
    $textarea .= '</textarea>';
```

After that, return the $textarea var and do an echo display(); inside the Hello_Admin() function.

As an alternative, add the textarea to the other echo outputs in the Hello_Admin() function and use the display() function to return the raw result like:

```
echo "<textarea.....>".display()."</textarea";
```